# How can I enable or disable the eclipse new wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My RCP application (based on the Eclipse infrastructure) has several modules. These modules can be enabled or disabled depending on the status of the application, and this information is available via [variables](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions) (you can think about the active perspective).

Additionally, each module contribute to the new wizards (extension point "org.eclipse.ui.newWizards") to provide the user with the ability to create certain elements. But this is allowed only if the module is enabled...

Is there a way to enable or disable "new wizard"s depending on the status of the RCP application?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Activities and Contexts in Eclipse.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that's accomplished automatically. That is, if the plugin which your wizard belongs to is not loaded, your wizard will automatically be ruled out of the RCP active extensions.

Comment: My RCP app is composed of several plugins, but depending on the project type I want to show only a subset of wizards... hence even if the plugin is installed an available, I might want to do not show its wizards...